# Как в WPF сделать Background brush (для кнопки) типа nine-patch (из кусочков PNG)?

Tags: c#, wpf

Имеется готовый фон для кнопки в формате PNG. Векторного нет.

Кнопок много, они разных размеров.
Нужно "резиновое" решение, которое один тот же PNG автоматически (в рантайме) "порежет" на куски: левый-верхний угол, правый-верхний угол, левый-нижний и правый-нижний, а то что между углами - оно растянет по ширине/высоте как stretch или как tile (по желанию), и составит из этого background для каждой кнопки любого ее размера.

Повторюсь - именно в рантайме, то есть Styles и т.д.

(То же самое с pressed, mouse over, disabled, focus состояниями)

Как такое реализовать?
Есть ли что-то готовое?

Comment: Покажите пример того что требуется. Как я понял вам нужен один стиль на все кнопки?

Comment: @TomDugger да. кнопок много разного размера, стиль один и png один. стиль умный

Comment: Нужен пример, как именно хотите изображение разделить на кнопки. Распишите подробней, желательно с иллюстрациями.

Comment: @TomDugger Хоть как-то. Как вообще это делать? Background принимает Brush, значит, нужно создать класс-наследник Brush, пусть он называется NinePatchBrush, который будет работать по принципу ImageBrush, но еще делить картинку на куски, stretchить один из них и ставить полученную картинку

Comment: Очень хорошая вещь должна получиться, кстати. Не зря на Android nine-patch поддерживается из коробки.

Comment: не нудно создавать новый класс унаследованный от Brush. Есть класс CroppedBitmap - он может использоваться в качестве Source для ImageBrush. Принимает изображение и позволяет отобразить его часть в Brush.

Comment: если не потерял интерес. Могу пример своять.

Comment: @TomDugger Да, нашел уже. Но это надо в стиль каждого типа (будь то кнопка или комбобокс (у меня у всех контролов картинки такого плана)) ставить огород из ячеек (Grid или еще что-то), которые будут отображать все эти части. А хотелось бы - поставил Brush и все. Brush универсальнее, можно куда угодно поставить, хоть в кнопку, хоть в лист, хоть в окно. Жаль, что нет возможности нормально его наследовать из-за того, что там потроха internal.

Comment: Попробовал с помощью рефлектора скопировать код ImageBrush (чтобы потом переделать его), но там классы internal задействованы. Причем не только вызываются (это я знаю как решить - рефлексия), но и в самих определениях тех методов (возвращаемый тип или типы параметров) которые я должен override в своей Brush, вот как такой метод объявить - я не знаю.

Comment: Может все-таки сяду и разберусь. Кастомная браш - это уже из области "патчинга", "инжектов", кода который меняется в рантайме, в общем хак.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы использовать в заполнении нестандартный лэйаут, проще всего применить layout manager. Для этого традиционно используется `VisualBrush`, в котором есть необходимая гибкость.

Пример:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Background>
        <VisualBrush Stretch="None">
            <VisualBrush.Visual>
                <Grid Width="{Binding ActualWidth,
                        RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Panel}}"
                      Height="{Binding ActualHeight,
                        RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Panel}}">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.Resources>
                        <Style TargetType="Image">
                            <Setter Property="Stretch" Value="Fill"/>
                            <Setter Property="RenderOptions.EdgeMode" Value="Aliased"/>
                        </Style>
                    </Grid.Resources>
                    <Image Source="red8x8.png"   Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" />
                    <Image Source="black8x8.png" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" />
                    <Image Source="red8x8.png"   Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" />
                    <Image Source="black8x8.png" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" />
                    <Image Source="red8x8.png"   Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" />
                    <Image Source="black8x8.png" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" />
                    <Image Source="red8x8.png"   Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" />
                    <Image Source="black8x8.png" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" />
                    <Image Source="red8x8.png"   Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" />
                </Grid>
            </VisualBrush.Visual>
        </VisualBrush>
    </Grid.Background>
</Grid>
```

Это не режет PNG на куски (но вы, думаю, сами справитесь), зато имеет гибкость произвольного layout'а и произвольной сложности внутреннего контента.

Нужные `Brush`'и можно положить в стиль, да.

Результат:

[image: картинка]

---

Объяснение.

1. Обычно visual brush использует нативный размер контента и растягивает его под размер нужного tile'а (через `ViewBox`), это не то, что нам нужно. Отключаем этот механизм через `Stretch="None"`.
2. Прототипа нашего контрола нет на странице, поэтому контент задаётся прямо на месте.
3. Внутренний `Grid` привязываем к размеру внешнего грида. Чтобы не зависеть от точного типа, используем `Panel`, которая вводит свойство `Background`.
4. Обычно картинки растягиваются с сохранением пропорций, но нам нужно без, поэтому `Stretch="Fill"`. Чтобы не прописывать его у всех картинок, используем стиль по умолчанию внутри `Grid`'а.